# dpkg: error processing package tuxcut (--remove):

Tags: dpkg, uninstall

I am new on Ubuntu and I was looking for an option to net-cut here in Ubuntu so... I was trying to remove `tuxcut` but I got this:

```
sudo apt purge tuxcut
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
fonts-wine libieee1284-3:i386 libpng-tools libwine libwine:i386  
libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-0v5 linux-headers-4.13.0-21  
linux-headers-4.13.0-21-generic linux-image-4.13.0-21-generic  
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-21-generic linux-tools-4.13.0-21  
linux-tools-4.13.0-21-generic ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 python-wxgtk3.0 
python-wxversion wine32:i386 wine64 zlib1g-dev 
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. The following packages will be REMOVED:  
tuxcut*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,576 kB disk space will be freed. Do you want
to continue? [Y/n] y 
(Reading database ... 419130 files and directories currently installed.) 
Removing tuxcut (5.0) ... 
rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/run-tuxcut': No such file or directory 
dpkg: error processing package tuxcut (--remove):  subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing:  tuxcut 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)*
```

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and do:

```
sudo touch /usr/bin/run-tuxcut
sudo apt purge tuxcat
```

Enjoy!

What do these commands mean?

You created an empty file called `run-tuxcut` and re-run `sudo apt purge tuxcat`. If the file exists then `dpkg` continues doing the purge. If not, shows your above-mentioned error.